# Find index of two substrings with overlapping characters

Tags: python, string, find, substring

I want to find the index of two substrings in a string of characters given like this:

```
find_start = '1L'
find_end = 'L'
>>> blah = 'A1LELST5W'
>>> blah.index('1L')
1
>>> blah.index('L')
2  # i want it to give me 4
```

If I use the index method, it gives me the "L" that's the third character in the string. But I want it to treat "1L" and "L" as separate strings and give me the fifth character instead.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Or would I have to store everything except `find_start` in a new string and then try to index through that? (But that would mess with the position of everything inside the string).

Comment: Why is `1L` not a real `L`, but `EL` is?

Comment: `blah` is a string with value and `1L` is a string of size 2. Since you want to find the index of letter `L` in string `blah`, `index` will give you the index number of the first occurrence. Hence, `index` is give location 2 as it has encountered `L` at index 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [str.index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) method has *start* and *end* arguments that allow you to constrain the search. So you just need to start the second search where the first one ends:

```
>>> find_start = '1L'
>>> find_end = 'L'
>>> blah = 'A1LELST5W'
>>> first = blah.index('1L')
>>> first
1
>>> blah.index('L', first + len(find_start))
4
```